# Handling Push Notification on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I'm working on handling push notification and I get bug when the first notification success received and shows me the destination view controller. But for the second and the rest the application crash. I get the problem is the app doesn't receive the parameter that should get from push notification.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    //[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo=%@", userInfo);

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@"aps"];
        NSString *alertTitle = @"";

        if([userInfo[@"page"] isEqualToString:@"ga"])
        {
            alertTitle = @"General Advisory";
        }
        else if ([userInfo[@"page"] isEqualToString:@"cr"])
        {
            alertTitle = @"Customer Recommendation";
        }


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:alertTitle
                              message:[aps objectForKey:@"alert"]
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"View"];
        //set tag to id
        alert.tag = [userInfo[@"id"] intValue];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive)
    {
        [self movePageAfterReceiveNotification:userInfo[@"page"] withId:userInfo[@"id"]];
    }
}

- (void)movePageAfterReceiveNotification:(NSString *)page withId:(NSString *)pageId
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    UITabBarController *tabBarVC = (UITabBarController*)topController.presentedViewController;

    if (tabBarVC.selectedIndex > 0)
    {
        [tabBarVC setSelectedIndex:0];
    }
    UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController*)[tabBarVC.viewControllers firstObject];
    HomeViewController *homeVC = (HomeViewController*)[navcon topViewController];

    NSLog(@"Page: %@",page);
    NSLog(@"ID: %@",pageId);

    if ([page isEqualToString:@"ga"])
    {
        //redirect to homeVC 
        [homeVC loadDataGeneralAdvisoryFromPushNotif:pageId];
    }
    else if ([page isEqualToString:@"cr"])
    {
        //redirect to homeVC
        [homeVC loadDataCustomerRecommendationFromPushNotif:pageId];
    }

}
```

The error like this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CRDetailViewController loadDataCustomerRecommendationFromPushNotif:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14756d180'
```

Comment: in this VC loadDataCustomerRecommendationFromPushNotify: try may be a spell mistake

Comment: But the first parameter has been successfully loaded.

Comment: (HomeViewController*)[navcon topViewController] probbably returns view controller which is instance of CRDetailViewController, add your method to CRDetailViewController, or do something else with this controller

Comment: @user2432612 can you code for me? I didn't understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topViewController of your first navigation controller (tab one) is not HomeViewControlled but CRDetailViewController. As you can see the error message says `'-[CRDetailViewController loadDataCustomerRecommendationFromPushNotif:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14756d180'`

You probably want your HomeViewController to handle that information, because that view controller is the one implementing your `loadDataCustomerRecommendationFromPushNotif` method.

I guess you should call `[navcon popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` right before `HomeViewController *homeVC = (HomeViewController*)[navcon topViewController];`

Something like this, probably:

```
UINavigationController *navcon = (UINavigationController*)[tabBarVC.viewControllers firstObject];
[navcon popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]
HomeViewController *homeVC = (HomeViewController*)[navcon topViewController];
```